# Is a question about static electricity on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about static electricity problem with notebook. I think it more electronic than general physics question. Should I ask it here or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.  
If it's a consumer-type question, then [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) would be a better place for it, probably.  
If it's a design-type question, then it could work here on EE.SE.

What's the question?

Comment: It's truly consumer-type question. In short the question is "How can I reduce static electricity effect while using notebook?" So, I going to ask it at SuperUser. Thanks for help.

Comment: @MaksimKolesnikov that's indeed of topic here and on topic there.